# empty result when getting data from mongodb with mongoose and node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to fetch all my documents from a collection in my MongoDb DB but I can't do it. I have absolutely no error but it just returns an empty array in my console.

Model :

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const websiteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  id: {type: String},
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  url: {type: String, required: true},
  note: {type: Number, required: true}
});

export default mongoose.model("Website", websiteSchema);
```

File in which I want to use the data :

```
import express from 'express';

import Website from '../models/website.js';

const routerWebsiteList = express.Router();

routerWebsiteList.get('/website-list', async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const websitesToCrawl = await Website.find({});
    console.log(websitesToCrawl);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({message : "An error occured"});
  }
})

export default routerWebsiteList;
```

All I get in my console is [].

My data in my database seems good too :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I finally found what was the problem. The mongoose Schema was looking in a wrong collection named "websites". All I had to do was to specified the collection name in my model as following : ("websitesToCrawl" is the collection name)

```
export default mongoose.model("Website", websiteSchema, "websitesToCrawl");
```

Answer (score -1):

**Accully everything looking fine maybe you can use**

require for import files

```
const name = require('name')
```

and for the export file :

```
module.exports = routerWebsiteList
```

after that be sure you connected your database correct like this

```
 async function database() {
   await mongoose
   .connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL)
   .then(() => {
      console.log("Database Coonected");
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     console.log(err);
   });
 }

 database()
```

**Last detail is you don't need to put id on mongoose schema just remove it and finally change your model like this**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const websiteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  url: {type: String, required: true},
  note: {type: Number, required: true}
});

const Website = mongoose.model("Website", websiteSchema); 

module.exports = Website
```

I hope that will be helpful. If you will be stuck somewhere feel free to type here again.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried what you sent me but it still the same result unfortunately. The database is connected I have the message in my console. I don't know what is the problem...